# HTML Purifier Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, htmlpurifier

I found several posts stating that xss_clean is not sufficient for sanitizing user input. Many of them suggested to use htmlpurifier in codeigniter.

I don't know what htmlpurifier exactly does and how it does. How to implement html purifier.

Please guide.

Comment: Quick Google search bought this up on the Codeigniter wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/htmlpurifier/

Answer (score 1):

xss_clean actually isn't half bad, just don't expect it to be a magic bullet in the sense of 'I use xss_clean, now my whole website is secure'. 
You still have to validate input and escape output. Simply put: you have to maintain control over what people can enter in your website, and you shouldn't trust anything that is in your database, so you escape the data before you use it or show it. If you use xss_clean and form validation for sanitizing the input and you escape the output before doing anything with it or showing it, you should be just fine.

Good reads:
[Codeigniter xss_clean dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925720/codeigniter-xss-clean-dilemma)
and
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/188698